# c++ Using const in a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have never written copy constructor, so in order to avoid pain i wanted to know if what i have coded is legit. It compiles but i am not sure that it works as a copy constructor should.

Also do i have to use const in the copy constructor or i can simply drop it. (What i dont like about const is that the compiler cries if i use some non const functions).

```cpp
//EditNode.h
class EditNode
{
      explicit EditNode(QString elementName);
      EditNode(const EditNode &src);
}

//EditNodeContainer.h
class EditNodeContainer : public EditNode
{
      explicit EditNodeContainer(QString elementName);
      EditNodeContainer(const EditNodeContainer &src);
}

//EditNodeContainer.cpp
EditNodeContainer::EditNodeContainer(QString elementName):EditNode(elementName)
{
}       

//This seems to compile but not sure if it works
EditNodeContainer::EditNodeContainer(const EditNodeContainer &src):EditNode(src)
{

}


//the idea whould be to do something like this
EditNodeContainer *container1 = new EditNodeContainer("c1");
EditNodeContainer *copyContainer = new EditNodeContainer(container1);
```

Comment: Your copy constructor doesn't do anything that the compiler-generated one doesn't do.

Comment: Is there some reason why you need to write a custom copy constructor? In many cases, the default one should be fine.

Comment: i.e. when you want to copy data pointed from a member and not the pointer itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A copy constructor is a constructor that has one of the following signatures:

```
class A
{
    A(A& other);
    //or
    A(const A& other);
    //or
    A(volatile A& other);
    //or
    A(const volatile A& other);
    //or any of the above + other parameters that have default arguments
    //example:
    A(const A& other, int x = 0) //this is also a copy constructor
};
```

The above is specified in **12.8.2** of the standard - C++03.
so you are implementing correctly a copy constructor.

The reason it should receive a `const` parameter is that you're not changing the object you're copying from. If you call non-const functions on it, you're doing something wrong.

Also, in your snippet

```
EditNodeContainer *container1 = new EditNodeContainer("c1");
EditNodeContainer *copyContainer = new EditNodeContainer(container1);
```

you're not calling a copy constructor, because you're passing an `EditNodeContainer*` as parameter, not a `EditNodeContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one * symbol. Copy constructor expects reference to object, but is given pointer to object. Just replace `container1` with `*container1` as parameter of copy constructor.

Comment: you are right, since container1 is a pointer so he need to de reference it

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of a copy constructor can be an lvalue reference to non-const or an lvalue reference to const, but in practice it is always a reference to const (the deprecated `auto_ptr` is an exception).

You should not write a copy constructor unless you have to and you fully understand the consequences. If you are consequent in using RAII classes everywhere, you rarely need a custom copy constructor (unless you are writing a RAII class).

Also, please avoid raw pointers and `new` wherever possible.